# Can't find a licence definition for susy

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass

I want to use susy for a project for a big company. They want to know under which licence susy is. Can you provide me with some information? I was not able to find an answer to that question, neither by checking the [github repo](https://github.com/ericam/susy/) nor by looking at the [webpage](http://susy.oddbird.net/).

Comment: Go to GitHub, click `LICENSE.txt`.

Comment: Owww snap... thanks, I totally overlooked that. Normally you find that information somewhere on the webpage or in the Readme.md...